# Magento 1.4.2 - Adding an action filter to a block in CMS

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have the following:

```
<div>
<h2 class="subtitle">Featured Products</h2>
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="41" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</div>
<div>
```

...and I want to add an action method to it:

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
```

...but either I cannot add the action method here in the CMS or I am not formatting it correctly, can anyone help?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setColumnCount` is a method and AFAIK CMS directives can only specify attributes. Try putting the value directly:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="41" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</div>
```

(Code borrowed from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/cms_and_home_page/add_featured_products_to_home_page))

Comment: I have a theory their home-brewed forum is so slow no-one wants to help out there, clearly there isn't a shortage of knowledgeable mage users (Magentists?) on the web.

Comment: @clockworkgeek is there anyway that I can set custom action there. Something like `<action method="setData"><name>category_id</name><value>123</value></action>` which is not a built in CMS directives.

Comment: Normally, when you specify an attribute like `category_id="123"`, it is calling `setDataUsingMethod` internally. So you can write your own `setCategoryId` method and it will be called. Of course you usually don't need to because it is a magic setter. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify compound values in directives. You might be able to create your own directive with custom parsing, for reference see [`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::blockDirective`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php).